# Is there any well-written documentation for mxgraph?

Tags: javascript, workflow, document, mxgraph

I want to use workflow in my web application. I've decided to use mxgraph. My main problem is that it have very pure documentation.

For example I want to add items to toolbar for bpmn but I don't now how I should do that.

I need some sample that explain main methods step by step.

Comment: what is `bpmn`?

Comment: @AlexBuyny Business Process Model and Notation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is no technical documentation other than this:
[mxGraph Documentation](https://jgraph.github.io/mxgraph/docs/js-api/files/index-txt.html)